# Number of days is returning Error Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried a number of different things with this and the code on the View seems to be correct. However I am getting the error and I do not know why. The code is nested to only run if the item `!=null` however it seems to still look at the records that have a `null` date. I have even changed that to `.hasValue` and I am still getting the error.

Here is my code:

```
  @if (item.PaymentRequestedDate != null)
      {
        var dates = DateTime.Now;
        var reqDate = item.PaymentRequestedDate.Value;
        var days = (dates - reqDate).TotalDays;

       <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Requested: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentRequestedDate)</span>
       @if (days >= 15)
       {
          <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Past Due: @days days</span>
       }
  }
```

The error is on the line `var reqDate = item.PaymentRequestedDate.Value;` I have changed these to `DateTime` instead of `var` but the `DateTime` has issues with the `null` and the `TotalDays`.

I just want to display if the item is past due. `>= 15` days is past due.
Am I missing something? It shouldn't be looking at the records that do not have a date, right?

Also the date has to be a nullable `dateTime` Only when I send an invoice does a date get filled..
thanks for your help!

UPDATE:

Here is the PaymentRequestedDate

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
 public DateTime? PaymentRequestedDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please show the defintion of `PaymentRequestedDate`.

Comment: so PaymentRequestedDate is a nullable DateTime? Can you show the Class for "item" I want to look at the properties

Comment: sounds to me like "Value" returns a nullable date time

Comment: What's the type of `item.PaymentRequestedDate`? Is it `DateTime` or `DateTime?` (aka `Nullable<DateTime>`)?

Comment: Try cleaning up, rebuilding and running project again.

Comment: Could be you have not enabled recompile at runtime.  Maybe stop and restart the debugging session for the changes to take place?

Comment: In C#, type is everything. Do you know the type of `.ToTalDays`?

Comment: `var dates = DateTime.Now;` - that is really bad variable naming.

Comment: To answer some of the questions.. PaymentRequestedDate is DateTime?, It does recompile at runtime, Not sure what is meant by know what type .ToTotalDays means.

Comment: double TimeSpan.TotalDays {get;} is the type

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible sample of the problematic code (something we can copy/paste and see the error)? What you've presented looks fine.

Comment: Actually it is fine.Not sure why Elmah Error did not track the latest error, but it was actually an added @ inside an if statement. The issue I am having now is that the @days is showing up as a decimal 7.0245875458585632.. Not sure why!

Comment: You used `TotalDays`, which is the decimal representation of days. Use `Days` for a whole number representation.

Comment: @RufusL Yes i figured that out. It shows that in my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Completed code that works. As I mentioned in the comments the error was because of a additional @ inside the If statement. I use Elmah Error and for some reason it was not tracking that error.

```
    @if (item.PaymentRequestedDate != null)
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        var reqDate = item.PaymentRequestedDate.Value;
        var newdate = reqDate.AddDays(15);
        var isLate = (date - newdate).Days;
        var days = (date - reqDate).Days;
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Requested: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentRequestedDate)</span>
        if ((days >= 15) && (item.Payment == 1))
        {
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">Past Due: @isLate days</span>
        }
    }
```